# How to limit the scope of a Vue.js component's style?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am experimenting with single file `.vue` components and my first successful build surprised me with the scope of the component style. Generally speaking, I was under the impression that single file components would be self-contained, including the scope of their components.

The component `.vue` file is

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello {{who}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports =  {
    data: function () {
        return {
            who: "John"
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
div {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

It is built via `webpack`though the following `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './entry.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader'
        }]
    }
}
```

and the `entry.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import ComponentOne from './component1.vue'

//Vue.component('component-one', ComponentOne)
new Vue({
    el: "#time",
    data: {
        greetings: "bonjour"
    },
    components: { ComponentOne }
})
```

The HTML file binding all together is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        Greetings:
        <div id="time">
            {{greetings}}
            <component-one></component-one>
        </div>  
        <script src='bundle.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rendered result is

[image]

**The style definitions from `component-one` for `div` are also applied to the parent `div` (with `id=time`). Is this expected behaviour? Shouldn't the styling be confined to the component?**

---

Note: I can assign an `id` to the `div` in my component's `template` and would therefore contain the styling - my question is about why this behaviour is expected in the context of components self-containement.

Comment: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of the styling [will not be limited](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) to the scope of the component, unless you explicitly mark the style with the `scoped` attribute:

```
<style scoped>
div {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Furthermore, since you are using webpack to create a single bundled file, there would be no way for the browser to separate the styles from one component to the next, since all would be loaded and parsed at the same time.

If you wanted to lessen the footprint of a component on other components, you'd need to both scope your styles and utilize code splitting, although in your case, simply marking the style would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you David - this is exactly the core of my question. I tested the behaviour and it is now correct (there is a problem with switching routes, associated components and the rendering of non-scoped styles but I raised that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308191/non-scoped-styling-in-components-applied-only-once-when-switching-routes), your answer is perfect for the problem I had)