# Non-scoped styling in components applied only once when switching routes

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Vue.js [documentation for Scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) mentions that

> You can include both scoped and non-scoped styles in the same component

I built the [example application for `vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html) and used two single file components instead of the string templates of the example - the rendering is as expected.

I then tried to apply both scoped and non-scoped styles in the components. In the first one I have

```
<style scoped>
div {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<style>
body {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

and the second one

```
<style scoped>
div {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

<style>
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

The idea is to have the whole body background switch when choosing a specific route.

The `scoped` styles are OK - they change depending on the route.

The non-scoped ones do not (screenshots are from Chrome Dev Tools):

- on initial application load (non routed yet) the background is white (which is OK - this is the default one and there is no route for `/`).
- when choosing a route, the style for the body is applied correctly (say, `green` from the first component)

[image]

- when switching routes and loading the second component the background changes to the new color, it looks like from Chrome Dev Tools that the current style for `background-color` is overwritten. All the other components elements are correctly rendered (content and scoped styling)

[image]

- further switches keep the same background (and again, other elements of the relevant component are rendered correctly). There are no changes in Chrome Dev Tools (the last view above is unchanged)

In other words, **it looks like the style is stacked and previously overwritten properties are not updated** Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Ah my apologies then. I set some debug points and stepped through it, and Vue isn't modifying `body`'s attributes at all. After looking through the source, it looks like it explicitly listens to `body`'s children, so `body` would not see these changes. 

This appears to align with Vue's philosophy that you should not do anything with it outside of Vue's app container. I deleted my previous comments so as not to mislead others on their journey down the rabbit hole.

Comment: @Thebluefish: no worries, I also deleted mine too clean up. The non - scoped style is explitely set to modify the parent of the container. (I'll delete this  comment as well)

Comment: What I mean by that is that even the scoped style does not modify `body` - I have tried a couple dozen different ideas so far, and non seem to apply attributes to `body`. So my assumption is that this `<style scoped>` feature is meant to properly only work within the vue app, and therefore `body` is outside of that scope. I believe that the multiple `body` styles we're seeing here is just undefined behavior. It sounds like a great candidate to open an issue on Vue's github.

Comment: @Thebluefish: I tested with the Vue container (and not `body`) - same issue. I will submit a bug report if there is no feedback here for a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a [bug report](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6218) for this and it ended up being expected behaviour. The summary from the report comments:

[Thorsten Lünborg](https://github.com/LinusBorg):

> Yes, this is expected. Vue (or rather, webpack) does not insert and
>   remove these styles, as you seem to think. They are injected into the
>   head once the component renders, and never removed.
>
> A common pattern is to extarct all CSS into a single .css file in
>   production, which would have the same result.

My summary in the context of the question:

- initially (no route, no component rendered) nothing was injected
- the first component is rendered on route switch, its `style` is injected
- the second component is rendered on route switch, its `style` is injected and overwrites the previous `style`
- further route switches do not inject anything as each component was already rendered once. The last `style` used therefore stays as the authoritative one.

I will therefore fallback on binding the `body` class to the current component's `data`