# Style won't load when I press back button (VueJS)

Tags: css, web, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working on a web project (vuejs) which has some css styles loaded in.
Everything is working great except when I press the back button (mouse/keyboard doesn't matter) to go to previous page, then the css style won't load unless I press refresh. For routing I'm using the vue-router component

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Any error log or ?

Comment: no error log, nothing...

Comment: Try deleting your cache? What does the browser console say?

Comment: Are the styles being loaded in a 'scoped' component or are they in an external CSS file?

Comment: Maybe your issue is related to what was happening here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308191/non-scoped-styling-in-components-applied-only-once-when-switching-routes

Comment: If you look at the dev console are the styles still there, but overwritten by the css from the second component that is loaded? This seems like a possibility especially if you are not using scoped styles as mentioned above.

Comment: @MarinaMosti tried it but the problem still occurs.

Comment: @WhosDustin the style is loaded in a scoped component

Comment: @JohnM every component has a scoped style

Comment: What @JohnM said makes good sense, did you do <style scoped> on your tags?

Comment: @MarinaMosti as answered above, I've used the scoped tag in every component

Comment: Oops, sorry. Can you maybe post some code?

Comment: @MarinaMosti I don't think it would be any good.